# Error not caught in async/await Node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await, babeljs

when I run this function in Node (compiled by Babel):

```
(async function test2(){
    let pr = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(()=>reject(new Error('reason')))
    });
    try {
        await pr;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

You can run code in [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-3&code=(async%20function%20test2()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20pr%20%3D%20await%20new%20Promise(function%20(resolve%2C%20reject)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%3D%3Ereject(new%20Error('reason')))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20await%20pr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(e)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(e)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)()%3B). Both in Babel REPL and in Node my error is not caught (you can see that in browser dev tools in Babel REPL). When I start listening for unhandled rejections in Node (process.on('unhandledRejection'...) I got at least some notification:

```
unhandled at Promise {
  _c: [],
  _a: [],
  _s: 2,
  _d: true,
  _v: [Error: reason],
  _h: 0,
  _n: false } because of  [Error: reason]
```

I would like to catch those errors from try/catch - or any other way except process.on('unhandledRejection' , ...). How can I do that?

Comment: You have an `await` on the promise outside the `try/catch` block causing the unhandled rejection. Just rewrite the code to `let pr = new Promise...` and I think your code will work as you want it to.

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you @DanielB